# Fill NA according to group-value

Tags: r, data.table

[replace NA value with the group value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583739/replace-na-value-with-the-group-value) is not data.table-specific, although answer is similar, the answer below (to my question) is more elegant using data.table. HOW CAN I GET RID OF THE DUPLICATED TAG? THANK YOU

THIS IS DEFINITELY NO DUPLICATE OF [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)

I have a data.table like

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), A=c("Val1","Val1", NA, "Val2", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Val3"), B=c(1,NA,NA, 2,2,NA,NA,NA,3))
test   
    id    A  B
1:  1 Val1  1
2:  1 Val1 NA
3:  1   NA NA
4:  2 Val2  2
5:  2   NA  2
6:  2   NA NA
7:  3   NA NA
8:  3   NA NA
9:  3 Val3  3
```

with groups defined by "id".

I would like to populate the NA-Values with the values in their group. Do you see a solution?

The result should look like this (regarding character and numeric features):

```
   id    A B
1:  1 Val1 1
2:  1 Val1 1
3:  1 Val1 1
4:  2 Val2 2
5:  2 Val2 2
6:  2 Val2 2
7:  3 Val3 3
8:  3 Val3 3
9:  3 Val3 3
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Assuming you have the same non-NA value for every group. `ave(test$A, test$id, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x)])` and `ave(test$B, test$id, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there are only unique elements per each 'id' for 'A' and 'B' columns, after grouping by 'id', loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the first non-NA element and assign (`:=`) it to the columns

```
test[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]) , id]
```

---

Or do a join on the dataset after removing the NA rows

```
test[na.omit(test), names(test)[-1] :=  mget(paste0("i.", names(test)[-1])) , on = .(id)]
```