# How to copy value of a cell to other rows based on the value of other two columns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
zz = "Sub Item Answer
1      A   1    NA
2      A   1    0
3      A   2    NA
4      A   2    1
5      B   1    NA
6      B   1    1
7      B   2    NA
8      B   2    0"    
Data = read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

The desirable result is to have the value under "Answer" (0 or 1) copied to the NA cells of **the same Subject and the same Item**. For instance, the answer = 0 in row 2 should be copied to the answer cell in row 1, but not other rows. The output should be like this:

```
zz2 = "Sub Item Answer
1      A   1    0
2      A   1    0
3      A   2    1
4      A   2    1
5      B   1    1
6      B   1    1
7      B   2    0
8      B   2    0"
Data2 = read.table(text=zz2, header = TRUE)
```

How should I do this? I noticed that there are some previous questions that asked how to copy a cell to other cells such as [replace NA value with the group value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583739/replace-na-value-with-the-group-value), but it was done based on the value of one column only. Also, this question is slightly different from [Replace missing values (NA) with most recent non-NA by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/replace-missing-values-na-with-most-recent-non-na-by-group), which aims to copy the most-recent numeric value to NAs.

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace missing values (NA) with most recent non-NA by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/replace-missing-values-na-with-most-recent-non-na-by-group)

Comment: @MauritsEvers This seems to be a little different in that the link you are pointing to has NAs in the final output where as this question wants no NAs in the output. They are similar I agree but perhaps different enough.

Comment: What will happen if there are multiple rows for a `Sub & Item` with `non-NA`  value? Which one should be copied in that case?

Comment: @MKR In my actual data, there will be only one row with non-NA value for every combination of Sub & Item rows. Thanks!

Comment: @YiwenZhang Is it possible that both rows could have `NA`?

Comment: @MKR for each combination of Sub & Item, only one cell of row `Answer` would have numeric value; other cells are `NA`.

Comment: Okay. Then any of the below answer will work for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zoo::na.locf`.

```
library(tidyverse);
library(zoo);
Data %>% group_by(Sub, Item) %>% mutate(Answer = na.locf(Answer));
# A tibble: 8 x 3
## Groups:   Sub, Item [4]
#  Sub    Item Answer
#  <fct> <int>  <int>
#1 A         1      0
#2 A         1      0
#3 A         2      1
#4 A         2      1
#5 B         1      1
#6 B         1      1
#7 B         2      0
#8 B         2      0
```

Thanks to @steveb, here is an alternative without having to rely on `zoo::na.locf`:

```
Data %>% group_by(Sub, Item) %>% mutate(Answer = Answer[!is.na(Answer)]);
```

Comment: My answer is too close to yours so I am suggesting an alternative that doesn't require the `zoo` library: `Data %>% group_by(Sub, Item) %>% mutate(Answer = Answer[!is.na(Answer)])`.

Comment: @steveb That's a neat way! Never seen this. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to add it as an alternative, feel free to.

Comment: @steveb Done;-)

Comment: Depending on the input data, Answer may have more than 1 non-NA value per group, the max or some single value can be chosen in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
Data%>%group_by(Sub,Item)%>%fill(Answer,.direction = "up")
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   Sub, Item [4]
     Sub  Item Answer
  <fctr> <int>  <int>
1      A     1      0
2      A     1      0
3      A     2      1
4      A     2      1
5      B     1      1
6      B     1      1
7      B     2      0
8      B     2      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it was not intention of OP but I thought of situations where there are only `NA` values for set of `Sub, Item` group OR there multiple non-NA values for a group.

The one way to handle such situations could be by taking `max/min` of that group and ignoring `max/min` values if those are `Inf`

A solution could be:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% group_by(Sub, Item) %>% 
    mutate(Answer = ifelse(max(Answer, na.rm=TRUE)== -Inf, NA, 
                     as.integer(max(Answer, na.rm=TRUE))))

#Result
#  Sub     Item Answer
#  <fctr> <int>  <int>
#1 A          1      0
#2 A          1      0
#3 A          2      1
#4 A          2      1
#5 B          1      1
#6 B          1      1
#7 B          2      0
#8 B          2      0
```