# Replacing NA values to numeric values in groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have question about replacing `NA` values with numeric values in data.
if all rows are `NA` in the group replace them with `100` and else 
if there is any numeric value in the group replace `NA`s with those numeric values.

Similar posts 
[How to copy value of a cell to other rows based on the value of other two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920227/how-to-copy-value-of-a-cell-to-other-rows-based-on-the-value-of-other-two-column?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[replace NA value with the group value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583739/replace-na-value-with-the-group-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However I rather would like to have direct `dplyr` solution but those two posts have solution with `zoo` package!

```
df = data.frame(gr=gl(3,3),id=c("NA","NA","NA",131,"NA","NA",232,232,"NA"))

> df
  gr  id
1  1  NA
2  1  NA
3  1  NA
4  2 131
5  2  NA
6  2  NA
7  3 232
8  3 232
9  3  NA
```

it looks simple so I tried,

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  mutate(id_new=ifelse(all(is.na(id)),100,ifelse(any(is.numeric(id)),id[which(is.numeric(id))],NA)))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   gr [3]
      gr     id id_new
  <fctr> <fctr>  <lgl>
1      1     NA     NA
2      1     NA     NA
3      1     NA     NA
4      2    131     NA
5      2     NA     NA
6      2     NA     NA
7      3    232     NA
8      3    232     NA
9      3     NA     NA
```

all rows are turn out to be `NA` why ?

the expected output

```
      gr     id id_new
  <fctr> <fctr>  <lgl>
1      1     NA     100
2      1     NA     100
3      1     NA     100
4      2    131     131
5      2     NA     131
6      2     NA     131
7      3    232     232
8      3    232     232
9      3     NA     232
```

Comment: What if a group has two different `id` values? Or will it always have same values for a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your `id` column is a `factor`, not numeric, so none of the values will return `TRUE` with `is.numeric()`.  This is because you constructed it with `"character"` `NA` values. Construct it with `"numeric"` `NA` values like so:

```
df = data.frame(gr=gl(3,3),id=c(NA, NA,NA,131,NA,NA,232,232,NA))

df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>% mutate(id_new=ifelse(all(is.na(id)),100,ifelse(any(is.numeric(id)),id[which(is.numeric(id))],NA)))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   gr [3]
  gr       id id_new
  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1        NA    100
2 1        NA    100
3 1        NA    100
4 2       131    131
5 2        NA    131
6 2        NA    131
7 3       232    232
8 3       232    232
9 3        NA    232
```

You don't have to do anything special to make the `NA` values `"numeric"`. `c()` will coerce them from `"logical"` when you pass them with `"numeric"` values. Before, since `"character"` has a higher priority, `c()` was coercing that column to `"character"` when it contained `"NA"` instead of `NA`, and `data.frame()` was converting it to `"factor"` because of the default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

Just convert `id` as `numeric`. Also, for the else condition of the `ifelese`, I used `max` just in case the value is not unique. Change it to whatever suits you. I don't think there is a need for the complex else statement.

```
df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(id)) %>%
  mutate(id_new=ifelse(all(is.na(id)),100,max(id, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clever!