# How to copy value of a cell to other rows based on the same Subject ID?

Tags: r, matching, zoo

I have the following problem. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Date       Period  Subject    Skill
1.1.2020     1        1           1
1.1.2020     1        2           3
1.1.2020     1        3           1 
1.1.2020     1        4           3 
1.1.2020     2        1           NA
1.1.2020     2        2           NA
1.1.2020     2        3           NA 
1.1.2020     2        4           NA 
1.1.2020     3        1           NA
1.1.2020     3        2           NA
1.1.2020     3        3           NA 
1.1.2020     3        4           NA 
1.1.2021     1        1           4
1.1.2021     1        2           4
1.1.2021     1        3           1 
1.1.2021     1        4           3 
1.1.2021     2        1           NA
1.1.2021     2        2           NA
1.1.2021     2        3           NA
1.1.2021     2        4           NA 
1.1.2021     3        1           NA
1.1.2021     3        2           NA
1.1.2021     3        3           NA
1.1.2021     3        4           NA
```

I would like to copy the `Skill` value from Period 1 for each subject that took the test on the same date (in this case representing a unique group) to the same subject in Period 2 and Period 3. The desired output should look like this:

```
Date       Period  Subject    Skill
1.1.2020     1        1           1
1.1.2020     1        2           3
1.1.2020     1        3           1 
1.1.2020     1        4           3 
1.1.2020     2        1           1
1.1.2020     2        2           3
1.1.2020     2        3           1
1.1.2020     2        4           3
1.1.2020     3        1           1
1.1.2020     3        2           3
1.1.2020     3        3           1
1.1.2020     3        4           3
1.1.2021     1        1           4
1.1.2021     1        2           4
1.1.2021     1        3           1 
1.1.2021     1        4           3 
1.1.2021     2        1           4
1.1.2021     2        2           4
1.1.2021     2        3           1
1.1.2021     2        4           3
1.1.2021     3        1           4
1.1.2021     3        2           4
1.1.2021     3        3           1
1.1.2021     3        4           3
```

I saw a similar thread [How to copy value of a cell to other rows based on the value of other two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920227/how-to-copy-value-of-a-cell-to-other-rows-based-on-the-value-of-other-two-column) however there is just one missing NA value per group (and not many NAs per group). With the following solution from `zoo` package I am only replacing each NA with the most recent non-NA prior to it.

```
x %>% group_by(Date, Subject) %>% mutate(Skill= na.locf(Skill))
```

In short, I want to match the value of a cell to other rows based on the same Subject ID within a group.

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Try using `fill` instead of `mutate`, such as `fill(Skill)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
df <-
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                                    18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18628, 
                                    18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 
                                    18628, 18628), class = "Date"), Period = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                               3L, 3L, 3L), Subject = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                                                                        2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
                 Skill = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                 -24L))
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Date,Subject) %>% 
  fill(Skill)
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 24 x 4
# Groups:   Date, Subject [8]
   Date       Period Subject Skill
   <date>      <int>   <int> <int>
 1 2020-01-01      1       1     1
 2 2020-01-01      1       2     3
 3 2020-01-01      1       3     1
 4 2020-01-01      1       4     3
 5 2020-01-01      2       1     1
 6 2020-01-01      2       2     3
 7 2020-01-01      2       3     1
 8 2020-01-01      2       4     3
 9 2020-01-01      3       1     1
10 2020-01-01      3       2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just taking the max or min over the date and subject?