# Join two data frames by columns with different row lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, join, plyr

I'm using R `plyr`'s `join()` function to join two dataframes by columns, "country" and "year," over certain tax treaties. However, the "country" and "year" columns of the two dataframes carry different length with different number of unique values, something like the following. 
`df1` `=`

```
country year    treaty_id
A   1995    1
B   1995    1
C   1995    1
D   1995    1
A   2001    2
B   2001    2
D   2001    2
C   2015    3
D   2015    3
```

while `df2` has the complete lists of "country" and "year" values

```
country year
A   1992
B   1992
C   1992
D   1992
E   1992
F   1992
G   1992
H   1992
A   1993
B   1993
C   1993
…   …
G   2015
H   2015
```

for "country" A to H and "year" 1992 to 2015.
Is there anyway to match `df1` and `df2` by the "year" information given in `df1` (when a particular tax treaty was signed) and expand the list of country from A to H grouped by `treaty_id`. (Since there may be more than one treaties signed in the same year, so it needs to be grouped by `treaty_id`)
Such that I can generate another dummy variable `member` to indicate each country's membership in a tax treaty. The output should look something like this

```
country year    treaty_id   member
A   1995    1   1
B   1995    1   1
C   1995    1   1
D   1995    1   1
E   1995    1   0
F   1995    1   0
G   1995    1   0
H   1995    1   0
A   2001    2   1
B   2001    2   1
C   2001    2   0
D   2001    2   1
E   2001    2   0
F   2001    2   0
G   2001    2   0
H   2001    2   0
…   …   …   
H   2015    n   1
```

It will really appreciated if anyone could enlighten me on this.

Comment: `merge(df2, df1, all.x=TRUE)` ?

Comment: The question I asked is entirely different from the one you flagged. Also, the `merge()` function did not address what I asked for.

Comment: `df2 <- expand.grid(country=LETTERS[1:8], year=1992:2015);
df3 <- expand.grid(country=LETTERS[1:8], year=unique(df1$year));
df4 <- merge(df3, df1, all.x=TRUE);
df4 <- df4[order(df4$year, df4$country),];
df4$member <- !is.na(df4$treaty_id)`
and then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583739/replace-na-value-with-the-group-value

Comment: `library("data.table");
setDT(df1);
dtyear <- df1[, .(treaty_id=min(treaty_id)), year];
dt2 <- setorderv(CJ(country=LETTERS[1:8], year=df1[, year], unique = TRUE), c("year", "country"));
dt2[df1, on=c("country", "year"), treaty_id:=i.treaty_id];
dt2[, member:=!is.na(treaty_id)][dtyear, on="year", treaty_id:=i.treaty_id][]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for belated response. I applied `unique()` to get unique `treaty_id` and `year` combination (such that each treaty and the year it occurred is uniquely identified), and then using  `merge(x, y, by = "treaty_id")` to fill in the corresponding year information " for each `treaty_id`. Could you cut-and-paste your earlier suggestion as a formal response under my question, so I can mark it as correct answer which might be useful for future readers?