# Filling NA values for all obs within the same group

Tags: r, dplyr, na, zoo

I have a medical treatment data where some condition indicators (i.e., columns) are only available for some rows but in actuality, the same condition should be categorically applied to all observations belonging to the same treatment (i.e., `program`). Thus, filling NA appears to be straightforward (since they are all assumed to have the same value) but also not easy because when I applied the methods recommended by some previous threads (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040834/replace-na-with-previous-or-next-value-by-group-using-dplyr/40041172) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583739/replace-na-value-with-the-group-value)), they seem to have problem with filling string value, as the code shown below.

Is there a fix to this?

```
df_example <- data.frame(patient = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                    status = c("Active", NA, NA, NA, "Non-Active", NA, NA, NA, "Active"),
                    condition = c(NA, "I", NA, NA, "II", "II", NA, NA, "III"), 
                    program = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))

# I want to fill all the NA cells for columns "status" and "condition" by each program, the values should be the same for obs belonging to the same program

library("dplyr")
library("zoo")

df_example %>% group_by(program) %>% transmute(status=na.locf(status, na.rm=FALSE))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   program [3]
  program status    
    <dbl> <fct>     
1       1 Active    
2       1 Active    
3       1 Active    
4       2 NA        
5       2 Non-Active
6       2 Non-Active
7       3 NA        
8       3 NA        
9       3 Active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add `na.locf` with `fromLast` parameter, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df_example %>% 
  group_by(program) %>% 
  transmute(status = na.locf(status, na.rm = FALSE), 
            status = na.locf(status, fromLast = TRUE))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   program [3]
#  program status    
#    <dbl> <fct>     
#1       1 Active    
#2       1 Active    
#3       1 Active    
#4       2 Non-Active
#5       2 Non-Active
#6       2 Non-Active
#7       3 Active    
#8       3 Active    
#9       3 Active
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. The code works great, but one thing I'm a little confused here is that when I check if all `NA` cells got filled up `length(df_example$status[is.na(df_example$status)])`, it returns 6. Weird!

Comment: Do you have any groups that only have NAs?

Comment: No, they have at least one row that is not `NA`.

Comment: Also, if you enter `df_example`, R will return the same dataframe with those `NA` cells un-filled.

Comment: I did not assign it back to the `df_example`. You need to do `df_example <- df_example %>%....` Also, If all groups have at least 1 non-NA then I am not sure as to why some NAs remained unfilled. Share an example that exhibits this behavior please

Comment: After I assigned the transmuted object to a new dataframe (using the original name `df_example`), the `length(df_example2$status[is.na(df_example2$status)])` did turn out to be 0. I just forgot that one need to assign the transmuted/mutated `dplyr` object to a new dataframe in order to get the transmuted/mutated columns.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there is exactly one non-NA in each group:

```
df_example %>%
  group_by(program) %>%
  transmute(status = na.omit(status)) %>%
  ungroup
```

or if there are multiple non-NAs but all the non-NAs are the same:

```
df_example %>%
  group_by(program) %>%
  transmute(status = first(na.omit(status))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  program status    
    <dbl> <fct>     
1       1 Active    
2       1 Active    
3       1 Active    
4       2 Non-Active
5       2 Non-Active
6       2 Non-Active
7       3 Active    
8       3 Active    
9       3 Active
```

Comment: OP may be looking for - `df_example %>% 
  group_by(program) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("status", "condition"), ~first(na.omit(.)))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As with the solution recommended by @Sotos, when I check if all NA cells got filled up `length(df_example$status[is.na(df_example$status)])`, it returns 6.

Comment: @ChrisT. that could happen if some group(s) have all `NA`s.

Comment: But for my example data (`df_example`), that doesn't look right.

Comment: Assign the result to a variable and then look at that.  It does NOT modify the input. I have shown the output so you can see it does work.

Comment: Got it, I apparently have ignored this.