# Match missing value in a data frame to another value

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a data frame with some missing group information. I want to use the value to match to where the identical value is found to assign the group.

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(NA, 'group1', 'group2'),
                 value = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.3))
```

How can I see where the value of the NA group matches to another group, and set that NA value equal to that group? Here, the NA should be 'group1'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace NA value with the group value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583739/replace-na-value-with-the-group-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` in `base R`

```
df$group <- with(df, na.omit(group)[match(value, unique(value))])
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `merge` + `subset`

```
merge(df["value"],subset(df,complete.cases(df)))
```

which gives

```
  value  group
1   0.3 group2
2   0.7 group1
3   0.7 group1
```